# Visual SVN server anonymous read access

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I have moved my team SVN server to a new machine and while I was at it I updated the server version, we went from version 2.5.X to 3.5.9
We use the subversion authentication

But on the way the "Everyone" access which is set to read-only on the repository doesn't work anymore and now svn requests an account and password when checking things out and when browsing the repobrowser. While before we could access the data anonymously.

For now I have added a guest account with read-only access but it isn't ideal.

Here is the content of VisualSVN-SvnAuthz inside Repository/conf/

```
[/]
*=r
guest=r
@DEV=rw
```

It seems like a bug, but maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN Server does not support anonymous access now. User has to be authenticated and authorized to have access to repository contents. See the suggestion I made on similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59861505/761095